# How to without re query modelA->relatedModelB->modelA

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When Laravel Eloquent calls a relation property that indicates the original model of the relation destination from a certain model, it issues a re-query and returns the original model.
Is there a way to return the original model without issuing a requery?

In `posts->first()->author`, laravel execute query `select * from "users" where "users"."id" = ? limit 1`.

I hope no execute query, and `author` returns `$user`.

https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/348b2dea-ac2a-423b-86c5-6ec17593546e

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqvdO.png)

Comment: Try using `::with('posts.author')`.

Comment: @yaakov It execute ‘select * from "users" where "users"."id" in (?)’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without making a db query to load the author, when the author is the already loaded user, you can set the relation yourself

```php
Route::get('/', function() {
    $user = User::with(['posts'])->first();
    $user->posts->each(function (Post $post) use ($user) {
        $post->setRelation('author',  $user);
    });
});
```

now each post will have a author relation set on the current user.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: one improvement would be to set the author relation on a user model without posts, since now the loaded models go like: `$user->posts->author->posts`. The posts of the author are likely not needed for your use case.